# SFDX Test Code Coverage on deployment - CICD

Tags: salesforcedx, cicd

I am trying to set up a CICD validation which needs to check if the test code coverage is going below 85% on a Pull Request. I am using the below SFDX deploy command but it doesn't give me code coverage in the result.

`sfdx force:source:deploy -u testscratchorg1 -p force-app\main\default --checkonly --testlevel RunLocalTests --json`

Has anyone implemented something like this before or any suggestions??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Deployments used to emit coverage data, but that changed in some recent-ish version.

To get coverage/failed test information now, you need to add the `--verbose` flag

If you're using the `--json` flag to output results as JSON, the coverage information is contained in result -> details -> runTestResult -> codeCoverage. The "numLocations" gives you the total number of coverable lines for a class, and the "numLocationsNotCovered" gives you the number of lines not covered.

You'll need to calculate the percentage yourself (`1 - uncovered/total`)

If you're using the `--json` flag, it appears that you don't need `--verbose`. `--verbose` seems to add to the printed information written to std out (i.e. the console/terminal/command-line)

Comment: Derek, I have used --verbose. Can you point out to me in the response where I can find the test coverage? It just shows a message if the test class has less than 75%. "codeCoverageWarnings": {
              "id": "01p0U00000FKl9D",
              "message": "Test coverage of selected Apex Class is 0%, at least 75% test coverage is required",
              "name": "ParentQuestion",
              "namespace": {
                "$": {
                  "xsi:nil": "true"
                }
              }
            }

Comment: @Numaan Took me a while to be able to do a deployment myself to check this. I've edited my answer with my findings.